# Shortening a SQL server select count query

Tags: sql-server, count

I relatively new to SQL and I am trying to create a select count query. It is basically a repeated expression several times over with different conditions. Is there a way of making the code more efficient as I have over 20 different 'condition groups'. Here is an example showing 2 condition groups.

```
(select count(vps.PrimaryKey) 
   from V_PatentSummarized vps 
            inner join V_TechnologySummarized vts 
                  on vts.PrimaryKey=vps.TechnolFK 
  where (vts.ClientDepartments like '%22%' or vts.ClientDepartments like '%12%') 
    and vps.FileDate between '2015-11-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         and '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000') as Sciences

(select count(vps.PrimaryKey) 
   from V_PatentSummarized vps 
          inner join V_TechnologySummarized vts 
                on vts.PrimaryKey=vps.TechnolFK 
  where (vts.ClientDepartments like '%36%' or vts.ClientDepartments like '%42%') 
    and vps.FileDate between '2015-11-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         and '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000') as Arts
```

Comment: There is no such construct in SQL Server as `( ...) as "Alias"`. It can be part of a query, so to combine 2 queries you need to provide whole query.

Comment: You're right that it is part of a whole query:
`Select vts1.TechID, (select count...) as Sciences, (select count...) as Arts
from V_TechnologySummarized vts1 where vts1.TechID = '00-000'`

Comment: I think you can combine 2 answers so the code was more easily readable.

Comment: I will try that thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as all those subqueries use the same FROM clause, you can shorten this with CASE statements:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN (vts.ClientDepartments like '%22%' or vts.ClientDepartments like '%12%') 
    and vps.FileDate between '2015-11-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         and '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000'
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sciences
 SUM(CASE WHEN (vts.ClientDepartments like '%36%' or vts.ClientDepartments like '%42%') 
    and vps.FileDate between '2015-11-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         and '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000'
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Arts
   from V_PatentSummarized vps 
          inner join V_TechnologySummarized vts 
                on vts.PrimaryKey=vps.TechnolFK
```

Also, if all of the subqueries have the same FileDate range, you can move that filter down to the main WHERE clause, instead of putting it in each CASE expression.

Answer (score 1):

try to have a view, You also need to differentiate same columns in View

```
create view vwname
as
select * 
   from V_PatentSummarized vps 
            inner join V_TechnologySummarized vts 
                  on vts.PrimaryKey=vps.TechnolFK 
  where 
     vps.FileDate between '2015-11-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         and '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000'
```

----- now you can query like

```
   select count(primarykey) from vwname where clauses
```